# ASIFormDataRequest inside requestFinished method

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I use an ASIFormDataRequest to log into the server, managing the response inside requestFinished method. If the response is ok, I need to launch another request to the server to download a JSON. Where should I manage the response (since I am launching the second request from the requestFinished method...)? Should make the second request synchronous? (if i am right, that would get the response from the server without a requestFinished method)

Any advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
```

You basically define the success/failure selectors. The `ASIHTTPRequest` ["How to use" section](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

---

**Update 1.0**

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

This is the default handler for the request finished. I think you will receive it as well with the "custom" selectors.

Comment: Hmmm i wouldn't have access to the actual response inside these methods, would i?

Comment: Ah, I understand, instead of receiving it in the requestFinished method i will receive it in the method set with setDidFinishSelector. Thank you!